# Security headers disappear on Wordpress pages

Tags: htaccess, security, headers

I am facing a problem that both me and my host support team were unable to untangle. I have included security headers in my .htaccess file (see below), but I get inconsistent results:

- All the headers appear when I check a file: [Test on a file (SecurityHeaders)](https://securityheaders.com/?q=www.i3italy.org%2Flicense.txt&followRedirects=on)
- None of the headers appears when I check the homepage, or any post page: [Test on the homepage (SecurityHeaders)](https://securityheaders.com/?q=www.i3italy.org&followRedirects=on)
- And, finally, only some of the headers appear when I check a picture: [Test on a picture (SecurityHeaders)](https://securityheaders.com/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.i3italy.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2022%2F08%2Fsostienii3italy-930x620.png&followRedirects=on) - but according to this other scanner, they all appear on the picture [Test on a picture (Serpworx)](https://www.serpworx.com/check-security-headers/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.i3italy.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2022%2F08%2Fsostienii3italy-930x620.png)... but this other scanner agrees that the homepage has no headers!

I am using the W3 Total Cache plugin, but configured as "Disk: Basic" and set to not set any additional caching policy (indeed, unlike before, nothing else appears in the .htaccess file). I am also using Cloudflare as CDN through W3TC.

I am also using "Jetpack" and "Really Simple SSL" among other plugins, but Jetpack is configured with every 'Performance' setting off, and Really Simple SSL does not seem to matter if I turn it on and off.

Clearly it's some Wordpress shenaningan, but which one? I genuinely do not understand, I'd appreciate if anyone had any suggestion!

In my .htaccess file I have put this:

```
# Really Simple SSL
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS 
Header set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests"
Header set X-XSS-Protection "0"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header set Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" 
Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set Permissions-Policy "geolocation=(); midi=();notifications=();push=();sync-xhr=();accelerometer=(); gyroscope=(); magnetometer=(); payment=(); camera=(); microphone=();usb=(); xr=();speaker=(self);vibrate=();fullscreen=(self);" 
Header set Feature-Policy "camera 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; geolocation *; microphone 'self' 
</IfModule>
# End Really Simple SSL
```

Comment: Have you tried without Jetpack, W3TC and Cloudflare? You only mentioned turning off Really Simply SSL.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that too and it did not seem to matter. However, I need those plugins so if one of them were the issue I'd need to figure out an alternative or a change to their settings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't changed anything significant, but all the headers (as of today) show up and I get A+ reports from those websites.

However, several plugins were updated in the past weeks, so one of the updates must have done it.

All's well that ends well!

Answer (score 0):

*The below only temporarily solves the issues. I ran into the missing header issues was a new cache file was generated.

I use several of the plugins you mentioned and recently noticed the same issue which drove me crazy as I manually confirmed that all of the headers were present in the correct files. I was able to resolve the issue by deleting my cache in WP Super Cache and confirmed that everything was back to working as expected by running a followup scan on SecurityHeaders.

Comment: Unfortunately resetting my cache doesn't seem to do the trick for me, but I'm glad it did for you.

But I just tested again and now it works?!?!?!